# For security, is it safe to pass new String(char[]) as an argument for passwords to a method that only accepts string as parameter?

Tags: java, string, security, passwords

I've read that for passwords, it's more ideal to use `char[]` since `Strings` are immutable.
Problem is, I need to pass a password argument to a third party dependency that invokes an http call. It only accepts strings. The call involves sending in a password in the message, so I use the method:

```
new Request.Builder()
    .url("notmyapi.com/login")
    .method("POST", new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("name", username)
        .add("password", password)
        .build())
    .build()
```

I know it's probably bad that the web api is just accepting a password as it is instead of accepting a base64 version or whatever, but it's not mine, and I just simply have to do my job.

Question:

Since I'm now passing around the password as `char[]`, but the `.add(key, value)` method above accepts only a string, is it safe to do `.add("password", new String(password))` ? Will this not create a new String instance in the memory which I'm supposedly trying to avoid for security concerns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've read that for passwords, it's more ideal to use `char[]` since `Strings` are immutable.

That's not the (whole) reason. The actual reasoning is:

1. You are using passwords for security.
2. A bad guy may be able to get a memory dump of a running JVM ... or extract a partial dump from the disk blocks that hold (or held) the JVM's memory pages.  That dump may contain passwords in clear text.
3. To mitigate this, one can (should) overwrite the memory containing the passwords when they are no longer required.
4. It is hard to overwrite a `String` since it is immutable.

But if you examine each of those points, there are assumptions that can be questioned.

1. Passwords are not a good way of implementing security.  For high grade security you should be using public/private key or secret key authentication.  So either you are talking about passwords that are "less important" to your system ... or you have a bigger problem than the one you are trying to address here.
2. If the bad guy can read JVM memory or the page file, they are pretty deep into your infrastructure.  You are already fatally compromised.  Furthermore, if they are in this deep, they can most likely find other ways to steal the passwords; e.g. stealing your SSL Cert's private key and snooping / decoding the encrypted network traffic.
3. This is only a mitigation:

   - The passwords will be in the clear in the `char[]` for a period.
   - Before the passwords arrive at your code, they will most likely have been converted to `String` objects by the servlet stack (or whatever framework you use).
   - Besides, this mitigation is only effective if you *do* overwrite the content of the `char[]` in your code after using it.
4. In fact, if you are really worried about this, it is possible to use reflection to erase a String; i.e. to mutate a `String` object.  In general, this is a dangerous thing to do.  For passwords / password checking, this might be acceptable.

In short,  I would argue that using `char[]` instead of `String` is too expensive to implement in Java .... unless you are prepared to completely re-engineer your web framework.  Furthermore, the benefit of doing this debatable, given the other ways that someone with deep access could steal the passwords.

---

Now to your specific question:

> Is it safe to do `.add("password", new String(password))`

If you consider it to be risky to use a `String` for a password, then that code doesn't help.  In fact, assuming that `password` is a `String` you now have two `String` objects in memory that contain the password text.

- If the API you are using requires you to provide the password as a `String` you have a problem.
- If the source of the password (i.e. how you get it from the user interface, servlet framework, whatever) is a `String`, you have a problem.
- Both cases it will be necessary to rework aspects of the code that you are interacting with to solve the problem.  This may be difficult.

And:

> I know it's probably bad that the web api is just accepting a password as it is instead of accepting a base64 version or whatever.

Base64 won't slow the bad guy down for more than a minute or so.  Ditto for any reversible encoding.  But I hope that you are insisting that the password only be sent over SSL / TLS secured connections.

Comment: `If the bad guy can read JVM memory or the page file, they are pretty deep into your infrastructure`
Actually it's a desktop client (can be downloaded by anyone) that authenticates the user via the http call the web api.
`If the API you are using requires you to pass the password as a String you have a problem.`
well, crap. 
`Base64 won't slow the bad guy down for more than a minute or so.`
Yeah I figured, i don't know much so I just threw in what I could mention...
Alright. Thanks. so the optimal solution would be is to have the web api not accept the password as plain string, correct?

Comment: If you are relying on password security when the password is being entered on a user's desktop, then your BIGGER problem is that the bad guys may have comprised the user's machine and installed a key logger.  That is much, much easier than trying to compromise the JVM that runs your client.

Comment: The optimal solution?  I think in this scenario you may need to accept that there is no solution that it is worth its salt if the user's desktop is insecure.  To get anywhere, you first need to secure the platform on which your client is run.  But the flip-side is that once you have secured the platform (and trained the user in how to keep it secure), your concerns about snarfing JVM memory are largely moot.

Answer (score -1):

No matter how you try on client side it does not matter about security because it seems a simple http client depending on your code in the post. So it will make a simple http request based on http protocol. So your password will go as a plain text in the body of http post request something like `username=john&password=12345`

IMHO you do not have anything to do from client side, the only work around here if the web api has a secure endpoint with ssl enabled then you can use it

Comment: it's a desktop client application that asks for username and password, so I do think that the client side matters.

Comment: Yes I did not think it can be a desktop app so you are right it matters and @StephenC has answered very well with almost every aspect :)