# Can we use String Buffer to store passwords in place of using char[] array?

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

It is preferred to use `char[]` to store passwords rather than a `String` in Java. But can we use `StringBuffer` instead of `char[]` to store passwords?

Comment: Basically, yes.  But you need to take the same precautions as you do with a `char[]`.  And the advice to avoid using `String` is ... umm ... misconceived anyway (IMO).   (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54175672/139985 for an exposition of the issues.)

Comment: When you use, e.g. `System.console().readPassword()` or `getPassword()` of a `JPasswordField`, you get a `char[]` anyway. Likewise, `java.net.PasswordAuthentication` or `java.security.KeyStore.PasswordProtection` expect a `char[]`. So typically, you get a `char[]` and pass it as-is to the receiving side. Copying the array into a `StringBuilder` and later on back to a `char[]` will not improve security at all.